# Asyncio - how to limit requests per 1 second?

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm new to asyncio, trying to make async calls to API, but when I'm sending more than 1 request/second the API responding with 429 status code - too many requests... According to API documentation, I should be doing only 1 req/sec.

Can not figure out how to do **only 1 request per second** for this code:

```
#Call to API
async def ps_request_marshal(converted_urls, device_input):
    global device_settings, data, tasks
    data = []
    device_settings = device_input
    tasks = []
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url={}' '&key=+key &strategy=' +device_input

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for page in converted_urls:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(session.get(url.format(page), ssl=False)))
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for response in responses:
            data.append(await response.json())
        print(responses)
```

Will much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, just added 'await asyncio.sleep(delay_per request)' to loop of task creation.

```
async def ps_request_marshal(converted_urls, device_input):
    global device_settings, data, tasks
    data = []
    device_settings = device_input
    tasks = []
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url={}' '&key=key=' +device_input
    delay_per_request = 1
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for page in converted_urls:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(session.get(url.format(page), ssl=False)))
            await asyncio.sleep(delay_per_request)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print(responses)
        for response in responses:
            data.append(await response.json())
        print(responses)
```